# Invisible cursor after FGLRX install (Debian Jessie)

Tags: debian, drivers, fglrx, cursor

After I've installed proprietary FGLRX driver (version 1:14.9+ga14.201-2) from Debian 8 Jessie repositories, my cursor became invisible. All mouse actions are working correctly, just can't see the cursor.

I've got Lenovo E420 laptop with Intel/AMD hybrid graphics, discrete card is Radeon HD6630M.

After install, I've created /etc/X11/xorg.conf file with `aticonfig --initial` . FGLRX driver seems working correctly. I can even see cursor in OpenGL apps like games. But after return to desktop it's gone.

I'm using KDE, but this issue seems not to be dependent on environment - tried eg. JWM.

When I delete xorg.conf, I can see cursor again, but driver is not working.

Kernel version is 3.16.0-4-amd64.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]

$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
        Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
        Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I guess I have the same problem. I have a mouse pointer on my second monitor though.

Comment: Turning off my laptop display moves the 'invisible mouse' to my second monitor.

Comment: This seems to be different problem from mine, but you could try new driver from Stretch or Sid repo (15.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing fglrx-driver (1:15.7-3) from Debian 9 Stretch repository solves the problem.